# presenceOfElementLocated in selenium unable to locate presence of Webelemnt

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.goibibo.com/");

    WebDriverWait driverwait=new WebDriverWait(driver,60);

    WebElement mydynamicElement=driverwait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='hdr_user_signin']/span/a[2]")));

    Boolean number=mydynamicElement.isDisplayed();

  System.out.println(number);
```

Answer i got is 'false' even though i put up a wait of 60 sec.

Don't know why unable to locate presence of Element....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mydynamicElement` has probably been located successfully, but it is hidden. You are not asking Selenium to find ONLY if the element displayed with `presenceOfElementLocated`.

Meaning `presenceOfElementLocated` and  `visibilityOfElementLocated` are not same. I believe you are looking for `visibilityOfElementLocated`. See the API doc [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

Comment: your understanding is correct but i found why it was giving false..due to maximize and minimize thing...it was unable to locate elemnt..

Comment: Is the information I provided answered your question?